# Antisamy converting single quotes to double quotes

Tags: java, html, owasp, antisamy

When i am trying to scan a html tag through [antisammy](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_AntiSamy_Project), It gives weird output. It converts single quotes to double quotes.

```
CleanResults cr = as.scan(dirtyContent, policy);
System.out.println(cr.getCleanHTML());
```

Input string - `<span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times, serif;">My name is Gourav</span>`

Output string - `<span style="font-family: &quot;times new roman&quot; , times , serif;">My name is Gourav</span>`

So, as you can see, the single quotes are encoded as `&quot;` which when decoded gives `"` instead of `'`. This is causing problems for me.

Antisammy Version - 1.5.3

Policy File - [antisamy-anythinggoes.xml](https://github.com/andresriancho/owaspantisamy/blob/master/Java/antisamy-smoketest/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/policies/antisamy-anythinggoes.xml)

How can i solve this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: How about replaceAll functionality of String, i.e. myString.replaceAll("'", """)

Comment: Have tried that but it may lead to problems where a legitimate double quote becomes single quote.

Comment: In that case I suggest, before `CleanResults cr = as.scan(dirtyContent, policy); ` replace `single quotes` with combination of character and reverse after the scan.

Comment: make sure the combination will never be in data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised this issue in the [Antisammy GitHub project](https://github.com/nahsra/antisamy/issues/200). This issue is now fixed :) . Please check the release notes for [Release 1.7.1](https://github.com/nahsra/antisamy/releases/tag/v1.7.1).

Answer (score 1):

try this simple solution

```
try
{
    .
    .
    .
    dirtyContent.replaceAll("'", "SOME_COMBINATION_OF_CHARS");
    CleanResults cr = as.scan(dirtyContent, policy);
    dirtyContent.replaceAll("SOME_COMBINATION_OF_CHARS", "'");// here is your sanitised data 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do something on expn
}
```

Comment: Thanks... Will check and let you know.